# How to use @@ROWCOUNT in a SQL Server derived table?

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple join (`left join`) derived tables in my query and one of them returns an empty result set which gives me a problem in my `WHERE` clause.

**WHERE Clause:**

```
WHERE (ISNULL(BalanceThis.Balance,0) + ISNULL(RL.Balance,0) + ISNULL(OtherPayThis.Balance,0) + ISNULL(RUPBalThis.Balance,0)) <> 0
```

**Query:**

```
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT AE3.IDNo, SUM(ISNULL(AE3.Debit,0)) AS Debit, SUM(ISNULL(AE3.Credit,0)) AS Credit, 
            ABS(SUM(ISNULL(AE3.Debit,0))-SUM(ISNULL(AE3.Credit,0))) AS Balance
            FROM AccountingEntries AE3 WITH (NOLOCK)                
            WHERE AE3.BookName NOT IN ('BFSL')
                AND AE3.GLAccount = '1.03.01' AND ISNULL(AE3.TC,'') = 'LAC'
                AND ((Datepart(MM,AE3.DateEntry)=Datepart(MM,@Date)) 
                AND Datepart(YEAR,AE3.DateEntry)=Datepart(YEAR,@Date))
                GROUP BY AE3.IDNo
            ) RL ON RL.IDNo = Loans.LoanID
```

**Result set:**

```
IDNo    Debit   Credit  Balance
```

Is there a way to return a static result set whenever a derive table is empty by using @@ROWCOUNT?

**like this:**

```
IDNo    Debit   Credit  Balance
EMP12    0        0       0
```

Thankss.

Comment: You should probably expand on _one of them returns an empty result set which gives me a problem in my WHERE clause_ . Perhaps there is another way to solve this issue.

Comment: Show us your `WHERE clause`

Comment: @Squirrel "  WHERE (ISNULL(BalanceThis.Balance,0) + ISNULL(RL.Balance,0) + ISNULL(OtherPayThis.Balance,0) + ISNULL(RUPBalThis.Balance,0)) <> 0 "

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do what you want:

```
WITH MyQuery As
(
-- This is your original query
-- This returns no rows
SELECT 'I have no rows' As OriginalQuery WHERE 0=1
)

-- Select from your query
SELECT * FROM MyQuery
UNION ALL
-- If there's nothing in your query, UNION ALL this part
SELECT 'I only appear when there are no rows' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyQuery)
```